# Popup to show youtube video inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, help me realize this function!

When clicked, a popup container, where load title and iframe (video from Youtube).
Any ideas?
Maybe there are plugins?

```
<a id="popup" href=""></a>

<a id="popup" href=""></a>


<div id="video-view">
     <h1>title</h3>
     <iframe ... ></iframe> 
</div>
```

P.S. Sorry for my English =)
[image]

Comment: I would suggest you reframe your question. It is not clear what you want

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: One window (id="view-popup") for loading dynamic data

Comment: I believe fancybox's iframe functionality is what you are looking for

Comment: @Ergec Thanks, but I have my own popup. And there are a lot of "garbage"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a class="popup" href="#!" data-link="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fbVD32w1oTo?enablejsapi=1" data-title="How to install SASS">SASS</a>

<a class="popup" href="#!" data-link="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Q0HFBy2BtfA?enablejsapi=1" data-title="How to install Node.js">Node.js</a>


<div id="video-view">
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".popup").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", $this.data("link")).css({"width": 400, "height": 300});
    var $title = $("<h1>").text($this.data("title"));
    $("#video-view").html($title).append($iframe);
    $iframe.wrap("<div class='class-video'>");
});
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/BrW5w/

Comment: It is the same, and then I modify! Thanks!

Comment: How to wrap this <iframe>? Using .append?

Comment: You mean this http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Yes, I need to <iframe> was <div>
`<div class="class-video">
      <iframe ... ></iframe>
 </div>
`

Comment: Nice!Thanks! Ideal code :)

Comment: Thank you. A little bit of css to make it more like a popout: http://jsfiddle.net/kf6sff00/1/

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on @Eregec answer to make the video show up in a popup.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    <p><a href="#media-popup" data-media="//www.youtube.com/embed/YoXa2Pl7Hk0">click me</a></p>

    <div class="popup" id="media-popup">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;
}
p {
    margin:0;
}
.page {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
}

.popup {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition:.3s ease;
}

.show-popup .popup {
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;    
}

.popup > iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-280px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("[data-media]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var videoUrl = $this.attr("data-media");
    var popup = $this.attr("href");
    var $popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");

    $popupIframe.attr("src", videoUrl);

    $this.closest(".page").addClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".page").removeClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup > iframe").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/WkyPc/1/)

Comment: JS fiddle result is not working.

Comment: It might not be working because you're using an ad blocker. I'm getting errors when I try to use this in my browser, but the fiddle is working.